# putting username and password into specific <tr> tags online

Tags: java, html, jframe, jsoup

I am building a desktop client for a university that allows them to create a dashboard of all of their power supplies on campus. The technology is already in place and the company has provided a website to view all of this but you can only view one at a time which becomes very annoying. My job is to design a desktop application which makes them log in with the correct credentials and then shows everything at once.

My problem is, I want to take whatever username and password they enter and enter it into a website. Here is the code I am working with on their website:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Log On</title>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1">
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache">
<link href="core.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
function placeFocus() {
if (document.forms.length > 0) {
var field = document.forms[0];
for (i = 0; i < field.length; i++) {
if ((field.elements[i].type == "text") || (field.elements[i].type == "textarea")) {
document.forms[0].elements[i].focus();
break;
} 
}
}
}
</script>
</head>
 <body OnLoad="placeFocus()">
 <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="message">
<tr>
<td class="edging"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td class="msg">
<form method="post" action="/Forms/login1" name="HashForm1">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td width="27%" class="dataName" noWrap><span id="langUsername">User Name</span>:&nbsp;    </td>

<td width="73%"><input type="text" name="login_username" size="17" maxlength="64" value="" />
</td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td class="dataName" noWrap><span id="langPassword">Password</span>:&nbsp;</td>

<td><input type="password" name="login_password" size="17" maxlength="64" value="" />
</td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td class="dataName" noWrap><span id="langLanguage">Language</span>:&nbsp;</td>

<td><select name="prefLanguage" size="1">
<option value=00000000 selected="true">English
</select></td>

</tr>
<tr>
   <td colspan="2" class="applyCancel"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log On"    class="btn" />
    &nbsp;<input type="reset" value="Reset" />
 </td>

 </tr>
</table>

</form>
</td>

 </tr>

</table>

</body>
</html>
```

What I want to do is focus on these three lines:

```
<td width="73%"><input type="text" name="login_username" size="17" maxlength="64" value="" /></td>
<td><input type="password" name="login_password" size="17" maxlength="64" value="" />
<td colspan="2" class="applyCancel"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log On"class="btn" />
```

They are the username log in, password input, and submit button

What I want to do is automatically fill these two textfields using java and then automatically cause the submit button to be activated for validation from the website. My problem is, I'm not sure how to go about it. I can parse the page using Jsoup in java but what do I do when I have that? Or do I not even use that at all?

Here are my 3 classes:

Main:

```
/**
 * 
 * The program requires a login already defined by
 * the administration. Then the program proceeds to
 * retrieve information from a local IP address.
 * 
 * This information is in the form of a webview
 * to help centralize all of the data for the UPS's
 */

package resourcemonitor;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JEditorPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;


/**
 * @author 
 */
public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args
     * 
     */

    private static JTextField tfUsername;
    private static JPasswordField pfPassword;
    private static JLabel lbUsername;
    private static JLabel lbPassword;
    private static JButton btnCancel;
    private static boolean succeeded;
    private static String address;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Resource Monitor");        
        JButton btnLogin = new JButton("Click to login");

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints cs = new GridBagConstraints();

        cs.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;

        lbUsername = new JLabel("Username: ");
        cs.gridx = 0;
        cs.gridy = 0;
        cs.gridwidth = 1;
        panel.add(lbUsername, cs);

        tfUsername = new JTextField(20);
        cs.gridx = 1;
        cs.gridy = 0;
        cs.gridwidth = 2;
        panel.add(tfUsername, cs);

        lbPassword = new JLabel("Password: ");
        cs.gridx = 0;
        cs.gridy = 1;
        cs.gridwidth = 1;
        panel.add(lbPassword, cs);

        pfPassword = new JPasswordField(20);
        cs.gridx = 1;
        cs.gridy = 1;
        cs.gridwidth = 2;
        panel.add(pfPassword, cs);
        panel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.GRAY));

        btnLogin = new JButton("Login");

        btnLogin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
               if (Login.authenticate(getUsername(), getPassword())) {
                //succeeded with the login

                //save the information in another class
                UserInformation UI = new UserInformation();
                UI.setUserName(getUsername());
                UI.setPassword(getPassword());

                //developer help
                System.out.println(UI.getUserName());
                System.out.println(UI.getPassword());

                //get rid of the log in screen
                frame.dispose();

                //create a new frame so that you can display the dashboard.
                final JFrame dash = new JFrame("DashBoard");

                //by doing this, the whole view becomes scrollable
                JPanel container = new JPanel();
                JScrollPane scrPane = new JScrollPane(container);
                dash.add(scrPane);
                //end of scrollable

                //contents of the dash
                JLabel introText = new JLabel("Welcome to the UPS (Unified Power Source) dashboard monitor\n" + 
                "Please select one of the IP addresses to access and click select");

                //adding it to the display 
                JPanel intro = new JPanel();
                intro.add(introText);
                dash.getContentPane().add(intro, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

                final String subject[] = {"10.117.1.1", "10.117.61.1", "10.117.183.1", "10.117.122.1", "10.117.3.1", "10.117.3.2"};
                final JList<Object> list = new JList<Object>(subject);
                dash.add(list);

                /*
                 * the IP addresses that I will be working with
                 * 
                 * 10.117.1.1
                 * 10.117.61.1
                 * 10.117.183.1
                 * 10.117.122.1
                 * 10.117.3.1
                 * 10.117.3.2
                 * 
                 */

               JPanel buttonUpdaterPanel = new JPanel();
               final JButton select = new JButton("Select");
               buttonUpdaterPanel.add(select);
               dash.getContentPane().add(select, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);


               select.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
                   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                       //Get the ip address selected in the list
                      address = (String) list.getSelectedValue();

                       System.out.println(address);

                       //destroy the selection window
                       dash.dispose();

                       //create a new window with the web view
                       JEditorPane jep = new JEditorPane();
                       jep.setEditable(false);   


                       org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc = null;
                       try {
                        doc = Jsoup.connect("http://" + address + "/logon.htm").get();
                       } catch (IOException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                       }
                       org.jsoup.select.Elements newsHeadlines = doc.select("tr");
                       System.out.println(newsHeadlines);

                       //URL request
                        try {
                            //whatever URL needed. Might be better just to parse 
                            //specific <div> tags
                            jep.setPage("http://" + address + "/logon.htm");
                        }catch (IOException m) {
                            jep.setContentType("text/html");
                            jep.setText("<html>Could not load</html>");
                            System.out.println(m);
                        }

                        //JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(jep);     
                        JFrame f = new JFrame("Test HTML");
                        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                        f.getContentPane().add(jep);
                        f.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(800,600));
                        f.setVisible(true);
                   }
               });

                //size and visibility
                dash.setSize(750, 400);
                dash.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
                dash.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                dash.setVisible(true);
                succeeded = true;

                } else {
                  //failed the login

                  //showing the error message
                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "I'm sorry but I do not recognize that username/password combination\n"
                          + "Please click ok or hit the enter key to try again");

                  // reset username and password
                  tfUsername.setText("");
                  pfPassword.setText("");
                  succeeded = false;
               }
             }
         });

            btnCancel = new JButton("Cancel");
            btnCancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    pfPassword.setText("");
                    tfUsername.setText("");

                }
            });
            JPanel bp = new JPanel();
            bp.add(btnLogin);
            bp.add(btnCancel);

            //by setting the default button, hitting the 
            //enter key causes the button to be clicked 
            //and activate the onclick listener
            frame.getRootPane().setDefaultButton(btnLogin);
            frame.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            frame.getContentPane().add(bp, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
            frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(325, 125));
            frame.pack();
            frame.setResizable(true);
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(frame);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }

        public static String getUsername() {
            return tfUsername.getText().trim();
        }

        public static String getPassword() {
            return new String(pfPassword.getPassword());
        }

        public static boolean isSucceeded() {
            return succeeded;
        }
}
```

Login:

```
package resourcemonitor;

public class Login {

    public static boolean authenticate(String username, String password) {
        // hardcoded username and password
        if (username.equals("user") && password.equals("pass")) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

UserInformation:

```
package resourcemonitor;

//this is a simple handler class where
//the information of the user can be saved
//so that it can be used later

public class UserInformation {

    private String name, password;

    public UserInformation(){
        //empty constructor
    }

    public String getPassword(){
        return password;
    }

    public String getUserName(){
        return name;
    }

    public void setUserName(String m){
        this.name = m;
    }

    public void setPassword(String n){
        this.password = n;
    }
}
```

I downloaded the jsoup from this [url](http://jsoup.org/download)

I know it's really lengthy but I really appreciate any and all help with this.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to create a [Jsoup POST http request](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.html#post%28%29) with the form data in it as parameters. JSoup can do it.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("the.url")
  .data("login_username", whatever)
  .data("password", thpass)
  .post();
```

I did not look much deeper into your question so far. If you need more assistance, ask away.

Probably you need to read out the cookies that you get as a response and set them to any further request.

Maybe the better choice for doing this is to use a full blown [Apache HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/index.html)

Comment: Oh wow haha I should have read the javadoc for jsoup... I havent tried it yet but i should by the end of the night (eastern time). I didn't realize jsoup thought that far in all of this. Thank you so much for the help! I'll let you know how it goes!